# Need to Sum the Column instead of Group by the Column in PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I run the query

```sql
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, Ord.LastDateModified) + ' - ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), YEAR(Ord.LastDateModified)) AS Months,
       'Week ' + CONVERT(varchar(50), DATEPART(WEEK, Ord.LastDateModified) - DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, Ord.LastDateModified), 0)) + 1) AS Weeks,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Ord.OrderNo != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NoOfOrders,
       ISNULL(Er.CurrencyCode, 'DKK') AS Currency,
       CONVERT(numeric(18, 2), SUM(OrderAmount * ISNULL(Er.Rate, 1))) AS TotalAmount
FROM [Order] Ord WITH (NOLOCK)
     INNER JOIN CustomerAddress Ca WITH (NOLOCK) ON Ca.CustomerCode = Ord.CustomerNo
     LEFT JOIN ExchangeRate Er WITH (NOLOCK) ON Er.CurrencyCode = Ca.CurrencyCode
WHERE Ord.IsDeleted = 0
  AND Ord.Approved = 1
  AND MONTH(Ord.LastDateModified) = 11
GROUP BY 'Week ' + CONVERT(varchar(50), DATEPART(WEEK, Ord.LastDateModified) - DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, Ord.LastDateModified), 0)) + 1),
         DATENAME(MONTH, Ord.LastDateModified) + ' - ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), YEAR(Ord.LastDateModified)),
         YEAR(Ord.LastDateModified),
         MONTH(Ord.LastDateModified),
         ISNULL(Er.CurrencyCode, 'DKK');
```

I got below Result

```
Months          Weeks   NoOfOrders  Currency    total amount
November-2020   Week4   1             EUR       24778.12
November-2020   Week4   1             DKK       14954.76
November-2020   Week5   3             DKK       31556.80
November-2020   Week5   2             EUR       6994.48
```

If I run the query inside Pivot Table

```
Select * From 
(
  <Above Query run inside this block>
) As Ml
PIVOT
(
    Max(TotalAmount)
    FOR [Currency] IN ([DKK],[CHF], [EUR],[GBP],[NOK],[PLN], [RUB],[SEK],[USD]) 
) As pvt
```

I am expected result like

```
Months          Weeks  NoOfOrders   DKK     CHF     EUR    GBP     NOK      PLN     RUB  SEK    USD
November-2020   Week 4   2        14954.76  NULL  24778.12 NULL    NULL     NULL    NULL NULL   NULL
November-2020   Week 5   5        31556.80  NULL  6994.48  NULL    NULL     NULL    NULL NULL   NULL
```

But I got the result below (instead of Sum NoofOrders Group by it automatically)

```
Months          Weeks  NoOfOrders   DKK     CHF     EUR    GBP     NOK      PLN     RUB  SEK    USD
November-2020   Week 4    1       14954.76  NULL  24778.12 NULL    NULL     NULL    NULL NULL   NULL
November-2020   Week 5    3       31556.80  NULL    NULL   NULL    NULL     NULL    NULL NULL   NULL
November-2020   Week 5    2       NULL      NULL  6994.48 NULL    NULL      NULL    NULL NULL   NULL
```

Kindly help me to `Sum(NoOfOrders)` by default Pivot Group it into a single row.

Comment: Please consider using whitespace and linebreaks well when writing any language; your SQL is next to impossible to read.

Comment: Also, I do you really need those `NOLOCK` hints? Do you understand the implications of using them? [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: I am new to this. So it Required 15+ Reputation to Upvote any answer @DaleK

Comment: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/397219)

Comment: It's also a good idea to be consistent with your scripting style; for instance, if you use CAPITALS for your SQL statements, then you should use them everywhere.  Also, [give your columns aliases](http://sqlserverservices.co.uk/articles/Column%20Aliases/Column%20Aliases.html), rather than relying on (in this case) SQL Server to give them names; though it's usually predictable, this may not always be the case (for instance, someone may have to add another column before any of yours), and try not to `SELECT *`.

Comment: Yes Sure, Can you help me to resolve this issue Sum(NoOfOrders) instead of Group by using pivot table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use conditional aggregation:

```
WITH t AS (
      <your query here>
     )
SELECT t.Months, t.Weeks,
        Sum(t.NoOfOrders) As NoOfOrders,
        Sum(CASE WHEN Currency = 'DKK' THEN TotalAmount END) as DKK,
        Sum(CASE WHEN Currency = 'CHF' THEN TotalAmount END) as CHF,
        . . . 
FROM 
FROM t
GROUP BY t.Months, t.Weeks
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry about answer instead of comment because reputation points not enough.
Does someone know a solution without use GROUP BY? Especially if dynamic pivot is needed...
However I post the working solution with GROUP BY and with fixed pivot from KIR's question:

```
SELECT t.Months, t.Weeks
    , Sum(t.NoOfOrders) As NoOfOrders,Sum(t.[DKK]) As DKK, Sum(t.[CHF]) As CHF
    , Sum(t.[EUR]) As EUR, Sum(t.[GBP]) As GBP, Sum(t.[NOK]) As NOK, Sum(t.[PLN]) As PLN
    , Sum(t.[RUB]) As RUB, Sum(t.[SEK]) As SEK, Sum(t.[USD]) As USD
FROM 
 (SELECT * FROM 
     (
     <Above Query run inside this block>
     ) As Ml
     PIVOT
     (
     Max(TotalAmount)
     FOR [Currency] IN ([DKK],[CHF],[EUR],[GBP],[NOK],[PLN],[RUB],[SEK],[USD]) 
     ) As pvt
) t
GROUP BY t.Months, t.Weeks
```